# Why isn't structuremap picking up my HomeController?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, structuremap

This is asp.net mvc3.

When I try and go to my home/index action:

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private IBar bar;

        public HomeController(IBar bar)
        {
            this.bar = bar;
        }

        //
        // GET: /Home/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "hello world yo: " + bar.SayHi();

            return View();
        }

}

public interface IBar
{
    string SayHi();
}

public class Bar : IBar
{
    public string SayHi()
    {
        return "Hello from BarImpl!";
    }
}
```

I get the error:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
public IController Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
Line 98:         {
Line 99:             return container.GetInstance(controllerType) as IController;
Line 100:            
Line 101:        }
```

**Do I have to somehow manually wire up each and every controller class?**

My global.asax.cs has:

```
 protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

            IContainer container = new Container(
                x =>
                    {
                        x.Scan(s =>
                        {
                            s.AssembliesFromApplicationBaseDirectory();
                            s.WithDefaultConventions();
                            s.LookForRegistries();
                        }
                    );
                        x.For<IControllerActivator>().Use<StructureMapControllerActivator>();
                        x.For<IBar>().Use<Bar>();
                    }
                   );


            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new StructuredMapDependencyResolver(container));
        }
```

And my structured map related classes:

```
public class StructuredMapDependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver
    {
        private IContainer container;
        public StructuredMapDependencyResolver(IContainer container)
        {
            this.container = container;
        }

        public object GetService(Type serviceType)
        {
            if (serviceType.IsAbstract || serviceType.IsInterface)
            {
                return container.TryGetInstance(serviceType);
            }
            return container.GetInstance(serviceType);
        }

        public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type servicesType)
        {
            //return container.GetAllInstances(servicesType) as IEnumerable<object>;
            return container.GetAllInstances<object>()

            .Where(s => s.GetType() == servicesType);
        }

    }

    public class StructureMapControllerActivator : IControllerActivator
    {
        private IContainer container;
        public StructureMapControllerActivator(IContainer container)
        {
            container = container;
        }


        public IController Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
        {
            return container.GetInstance(controllerType) as IController;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Which object is causing the `NullReferenceException`?

Comment: Good question, it seems the container is null!  I put a breakpoint in my global.asax.cs Application_Start method, and it seems somehow the StrucureMapControllerActivator is being called first as it goes there?  How is that possible?

Comment: ah, the problem was:  container = container should have been this.container = container!   I guess I should prefix private vars with _ after all!

Comment: It's always something simple that gets you, eh? :)

Comment: too bad you didn't write an answer, I can only upvote your comment.

Comment: I felt a bit odd posting an answer you figured out yourself, but since you ask... :)

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked which object is giving you the `NullReferenceException`?

It looks like you're assigning `container` to itself here:

```
private IContainer container;
public StructureMapControllerActivator(IContainer container)
{
    container = container;
}
```

So the member variable is never set. Change the line in the constructor to `this.container = container` and you'll be good to go.